# Hibernate ServiceImplementation throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with my program using Spring and Hibernate.
I have this classes:
**departament.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="apps_departaments")
public class Departament
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="dep_codi")
    private String CodDep;

    @Column(name="dep_nomc")
    private String nom;

    @Column(name="dep_nomm")
    private String nomCurt;
}
```

**departamentDAO.java**

```
public interface DepartamentDAO
{
    public void afegirDepartament(Departament dep);
    public List<Departament> getDepartaments();
}
```

**departamentDAOImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public class DepartamentDAOImpl implements DepartamentDAO
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void afegirDepartament(Departament dep)
    {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(dep);
    }

    public List<Departament> getDepartaments()
    {
        return (List<Departament>)(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Departament.class).list());
    }
}
```

**departamentService.java**

```
public interface DepartamentService
{
    public void afegirDepartament(Departament dep);
    public List<Departament> getDepartaments();
}
```

**departamentServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class DepartamentServiceImp implements DepartamentService
{
    @Autowired
    private DepartamentDAO depDAO;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    @Override
    public void afegirDepartament(Departament dep)
    {
        depDAO.afegirDepartament(dep);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Departament> getDepartaments() {
        return depDAO.getDepartaments();
    }
}
```

My configuration settings are:
**web-application-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.grupgirona.intranet" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:jdbc.properties"/>
    <import resource="webmvc-config.xml" />
    <import resource="webflow-config.xml" />
    <import resource="data-access-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

**data-access-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.grupgirona.dades"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Ok, when i try to acces data that way:

```
DepartamentServiceImp dades = new DepartamentServiceImp();
```

I get a NullPointerException (dades is null when debugging).
When I read the hibernate output, it seems not be strange things, and the connection with the database brings up (hibernate has been created the table app_departaments correctly).
I don't know if I missing something in configuration, or what.

I will appeciate any help.


**StackTrace**

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hpcds.grupgirona.dades.service.imp.DepartamentServiceImp.getDepartaments(DepartamentServiceImp.java:57)
    at com.hpcds.grupgirona.components.plantilla.LlistatDepartament.encodeEnd(LlistatDepartament.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1850)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:440)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:202)
    at org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView.renderMergedOutputModel(JsfView.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Could you please give us the stack trace?

Comment: Try to do something like this DepartamentService dades = new DepartamentServiceImp(); Also, please send the stacktrace error, so can identify the root cause.

Comment: @Manoj-Kathiriya that doesn't work :( thanks

Comment: EsteveBlanch : Yeah, you are right, i forgot your bean is marked with annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use this line

```
DepartamentServiceImp dades = new DepartamentServiceImp();
```

because you have an @Autowired annotated state variable in DepartamentServiceImp.

Spring doesn't encourage the use of `new` keyword. All the instances you need must be instantiated and retrieved from the spring context.

Have a setter `DepartamentDAO` in `DepartamentServiceImp` and set the dao if you still want to instantiate the object yourself.

Comment: Ok, i made some changes, I added `@Autowired DepartamentService dadesDepartament;` to my class, I don't use `new` keyword, and access data using that autowired variable, but dadesDepartament still are null.

Comment: Which xml file have you created the bean for DepartamentDAO in? It seems to be null.